# Get Rank from from Total LINQ Query

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have two tables.First is CompetitionUsers and Competitionpoints.
There is foreign key relationship between tables with ParticipateID.
In CompetitionPoints Table there are points  different points for multiple participateID.So I want to fetch Total Points and the Rank based on total points.So if there is multiple same total points for one participateID, the rank for that participateid should be same  .Its same like student Total marks and Rank from that Mark.
Here is my code.

```
var competitionusers = (from c in db.CompetitionUsers
group c by new { c.ParicipateId, c.CompetitionPoints.FirstOrDefault().Points }                                     
  into g orderby g.Key.Points descending select 
  new { Points = db.CompetitionPoints.Where
          (x => x.ParticiapteId == g.FirstOrDefault().ParicipateId).Sum(x => x.Points),   

Rank = (from o in db.CompetitionUsers 
   group o by o.CompetitionPoints.FirstOrDefault().Points into l                                                  
  select l).Count(s => s.Key > db.CompetitionPoints.
   Where(x => x.ParticiapteId == g.FirstOrDefault().ParicipateId).Sum(x => x.Points)) + 1,  
}).Where(x => x.Points != null).OrderByDescending(x => x.Points).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: You might be better off using a search engine framework for something like this, such as [Lucene.Net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/), which has built in support for document scoring.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding. Do you mean get the total marks for each student and then rank them in order?

Comment: I started trying to format your code to make it some way readable, but oh boy did I regret it.

Comment: @heymega Yes your are right.I want total points for each participateID and rank them in order.I am already getting total points for each one, but i could not rank them using LINQ

Comment: @Jamiec I just reformat the code.you can now see it easily

Comment: I found solution by taking iqueryable with new model.I get first all total points and than i wrote query on iqueryable query and got the Rank for Participants.Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your data model correctly, I think you could simplify to something like this:

```
var result = db.CompetitionUsers
    // group by total points
    .GroupBy(cu => cu.CompetitionPoints.Sum(cp => cp.Points)) 
    // order by total points descending
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key) 
    // calculate rank based on position in grouped results
    .SelectMany((g, i) => g.Select(cu => new { Rank = i+1, TotalPoints = g.Key, CompetitionUser = cu }));
```

Comment: Its showing me "System.InvalidOperationException" its not worked for me.

Comment: I found solution by taking iqueryable with new model.I get first all total points and than i wrote query on iqueryable query and got the Rank for Participants.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
IQueryable<CompetitionLaderMadel> competitionUsers;
            competitionUsers = (from c in db.CompetitionUsers

select new CompetitionLaderMadel                                
{                                    
CompetitionName = c.Competition.CompetitionName,
                 CompetitionId = c.CompetitionId,                                    
                                    Points = db.CompetitionPoints.Where(x => x.ParticiapteId == c.ParicipateId).Sum(x => x.Points),
                                    IsFollow = db.CrowdMember.Any(x => x.Following == userid && x.UserCrowd.UserID == c.UserId && x.Status != Constants.Deleted),

}).Where(x => x.Points != null && x.UserId != null).OrderByDescending(x => x.Points);
```

And then Wrote this Query

```
var q = from s in competitionUsers
                    orderby s.Points descending
                    select new
                    {
                        CompetitionName = s.CompetitionName,
                        CompetitionId = s.CompetitionId,
                        HeadLine = s.HeadLine,
                        UserId = s.UserId,
                        Points = s.Points,
                        Image = s.Image,
                        IsFollow = s.IsFollow,
                        UserName = s.UserName,
                        Rank = (from o in competitionUsers
                                where o.Points > s.Points
                                select o).Count() + 1
                    };
```